# spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:process-aot Get stuck

Tags: spring-boot, maven, graalvm, spring-native

run command: **mvn -Pnative native:compile** but execute here **spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:process-aot** Get stuck
try Ctrl+C after is work

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.whats-next

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                        <mainClass>com.example.techtest.TechTestApplication</mainClass>
                        <skipNativeTests>true</skipNativeTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Execution information：

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.0:process-aot (process-aot) @ tech-spring-boot- 
starter ---
c.example.techtest.TechTestApplication   : Starting TechTestApplication using Java 
21.0.1 with PID 20128 (D:\WorkSpace\project\tech-test\target\classes started by 86188 in 
D:\WorkSpace\project\tech-test)
2023-12-28T16:28:51.406+08:00  INFO 20128 --- [           main] 
c.example.techtest.TechTestApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "native"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**spring.main.keep-alive Change the configuration to false is work.**

**This has been fixed in springboot 3.2.1**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).